# To use context manager or not?

Tags: python, database, contextmanager

I'm designing a relational database from scratch in Python, and operations on the DB involve a lot of file operations. What i'm currently doing is opening the files in r+ mode during initialisation and closing them during the shutdown like so-

```
class Table:
    def __init__(self,loc):
        self.file=open(loc,"r+")
    def insert(self,key,value):
        self.file.write((key,value))
        self.file.flush()
        os.fsync()
    def __close__(self):
        self.file.close()
```

The alternative way of doing this would be to open the file in every call to insert using a context manager, but i presume that'd kill efficiency. 
What would be the preferred way of doing things given the context?

Comment: Opening a file is an expensive operation. Opening the underlying database file on each and every operation would be a terrible design.

Comment: @Tomalak That's true, but I was given a college project to design a file structures application. Rather, what i thought was to design a generic DBMS and then use it for the application. Just for learning and fun

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks for your guidance. Clears my head with the worry of having bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `with` block for the *instance*, and then the user can have multiple calls happen while the underlying file is open, while still ensuring proper cleanup. You can do this by making the class a context manager. For convenience, you may also want to offer an explicit close method; follow convention and name it `close`, not `__close__` (as there is not any special dunder method with that name).

Something like:

```
class Table:
    def __init__(self, loc):
        self.file = open(loc, "r+")
    def insert(self, key, value):
        self.file.write((key, value))
        self.file.flush()
        os.fsync(self.file.fileno())
    def close(self):
        self.file.close()
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.close()
```

Now you can do something like:

```
with Table('foo/bar/baz.db') as t:
    for i, j in my_data:
        t.insert(i, j)
```