# How to write a context manager wrapper for "open" that satisfies Pylint's consider-using-with

Tags: python

I have a dilemma writing a context/resource manager wrapper for a file object which passes Pylint, for use with `with`: Do I put the wrapped `open` call in `__init__`, or in `__enter__`?

Conceptually, this is a class that wraps `open` by accepting either a filename, the string `-`, or a file object (such as `sys.stdin`) and does 'the right thing'. In other words, if it's a filename other than `-`, it opens the file and manages it as a resource; otherwise, it either chooses a default file object (expected to be `sys.stdin` or `sys.stdout`) if the filename is `-`, or if it is a file object, uses that file object unchanged.

I see two possibilities, neither of which are working out right now: The wrapped `open` goes in the `__init__` constructor, or it goes in the `__enter__` context management method. If I put it in the `__init__` constructor, which [examples on SO suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62098676/to-use-context-manager-or-not), Pylint -- which I must pass -- fails on the `open` with `R1732: Consider using 'with' for resource-allocating operations (consider-using-with)`. If I put the `open` in the `__enter__` method, Pylint is happy, but I am not sure this is the correct practice, plus the problem is, in one use case, I need the file object in order to initialize a base class (and Pylint won't let me call the base class constructor in the `__enter__` method).

Some example code is in order. Here is code that `open`s in the constructor:

```py
class ManagedFile:
    '''Manage a file, which could be an unopened filename, could be
    '-' for stdin/stdout, or could be an existing filehandle'''
    def __init__(self, file_in, handle_default, open_kwargs):
        ''' Open a file if given a filename, or handle_default if -,
        or if it's a file object already, just pass it through.
        :param file_in: Valid filename, '-', or file-like object
        :param handle_default: What to return if file is '-'
        :param open_kwargs: Dictionary of options to pass to open() if used
        '''
        self.file_handle = None
        self.file_in = None
        if isinstance(file_in, io.IOBase):
            self.file_handle = file_in
        elif isinstance(file_in, str):
            if file_in is None or file_in == "-":
                self.file_handle = handle_default
            else:
                self.file_handle = open(self.file_in, **open_kwargs)
                self.file_in = file_in
        else:
            raise TypeError('File specified must be string or file object')

    def __enter__(self):
        self.file_handle.__enter__()
        return self.file_handle

    def __exit__(self, err_type, err_value, traceback):
        self.file_handle.__exit__(err_type, err_value, traceback)
        self.file_handle.close()
        self.file_in = None

    def handle(self):
        '''Return handle of file that was opened'''
        return self.file_handle
```

And here is how I would do it with the `open` call in the `__enter__` method:

```py
class ManagedFile:
    '''Manage a file, which could be an unopened filename, could be
    '-' for stdin/stdout, or could be an existing filehandle'''
    def __init__(self, file_in, handle_default, open_kwargs):
        ''' Open a file if given a filename, or handle_default if -,
        or if it's a file object already, just pass it through.
        :param file_in: Valid filename, '-', or file-like object
        :param handle_default: What to return if file is '-'
        :param open_kwargs: Dictionary of options to pass to open() if used
        :return: Managed file object
        '''
        self.managed = False
        self.file_handle = None
        self.open_kwargs = {'mode': 'r'}
        self.file_in = None
        if isinstance(file_in, io.IOBase):
            self.file_handle = file_in
        elif isinstance(file_in, str):
            if file_in is None or file_in == "-":
                self.file_handle = handle_default
            else:
                self.file_in = file_in
                self.open_kwargs = open_kwargs
                self.managed = True
        else:
            raise TypeError('File specified must be string or file object')

    def __enter__(self):
        if self.managed:
            self.file_handle = open(self.file_in, **self.open_kwargs)
        self.file_handle.__enter__()
        return self.file_handle

    def __exit__(self, err_type, err_value, traceback):
        self.file_handle.__exit__(err_type, err_value, traceback)
        self.file_handle.close()
        self.managed = False
        self.file_in = None

    def handle(self):
        '''Return handle of file that was opened'''
        return self.file_handle
```

I've pored over many SO questions & answers, but haven't been able to triangulate the exact answer I'm looking for, particular one that accounts for why Pylint flags an error when I ostensibly do the right thing.

Undoubtedly I've committed some Python errors in this code so any other ancillary correction would be welcome. Other ideas are also welcome but please don't get too fancy on me.

Ideally the class would itself behave as a full-fledged file object, but right now I'm focusing on something simple: Something that just manages a file handle (i.e. a reference to a regular file object). Extra gratitude if someone can provide some hints on turning it into a file object.

Python version is 3.8.10; platform is Linux.

Comment: The reason to put it in `__init__()` is so that you can use the object without using a context manager if you want to.

Comment: I think you just have to live with that warning -- you can't use a context manager because you're implementing the context manager. Can't you annotate that line to suppress the pylint warning?

Comment: @Barmar, I thought of that -- but the whole point of the exercise is that Pylint is flagging all my non-uses of a context manager as errors, so it's unclear that that is a goal in this scenario. Would the conclusion then be to put it in `__enter__`?

Comment: If you put it in `__enter__` then the caller is forced to use a context manager even if they don't want to.

Comment: @Barmar Yep, I could suppress the error, and that is an option; but given my lack of understanding, I want to explore potentially better solutions first instead of just adding a hack.

Comment: I don't think there's anything better, unless you want to disallow using your class without using `with`.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar, you've given me some valuable feedback!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need this to be a class, this feels like it's a lot simpler.

```py
import contextlib
import io
import sys

def open_or_stdout(file_or_path, mode):
    """
    Returns a context manager with either the file path opened,
    the file object passed through or standard output

    """
    if isinstance(file_or_path, io.IOBase):
        # Input is already a file-like object. Just pass it through
        return file_or_path

    if file_or_path == "-":
        return contextlib.nullcontext(sys.stdout)

    return open(path, mode=mode)
```

If you want to stick with the class, I think you need to return the value of `self.file_handle.__enter__()` in your implementation of `__enter__()` rather than `self.file_handle`.